# Organic Chemistry Reactions

Tags: organic-chemistry

Would any of you mind sharing the named reactions associated with the conversion of alkanes to haloalkanes.

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at this and the thionyl chloride reaction: https://www.chemguide.co.uk/organicprops/haloalkanes/making.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct process for this conversion other than nucleophilic substitution (I am assuming all types are not allowed eg. SN1 SN2 SNi ) but can be done by first elimination leading to alkene and next reacting the alkene with a halogen hydracid (HCl;HBr) .
Another process can be only for primary alcohols to oxidised them to carboxylic acid and then to the salt of silver .next perform the hunsdicker reaction with Br2 (It occurs through free radical mechanism )but in this clreaction haloalkane product is one carbon less than reactant .